# Can't connect Printer (MP980) wirelessly(or with ethernet) to computers

Tags: printer, ip-address

I have an N1 Vision, it gives devices an IP in the 192.168.2.x range and I've just connected my printer to the network using ethernet and on the printer's screen (the printer is canon MP980) it says the IP address is 169.254.149.85

How do fix this? As my computers can not see the printer and therefore can't print to it.

EDIT:
Well I tried it wireless and it still will not be found by any of the computers on my network, although it says the IP address is 192.168.2.6 and I can access the printers page by going to the IP address.

But because the printer has a USB slot for Flash drives it shows up in network as a computer (so you can acccess the USB drive over the network), an normally both the computer and printer show up in Network Devices but now only the computer is.

So it is aware the printer as a device is there, but it doesn't recognize the printer side of things.

EDIT2: The printer was working fine on all the computer then suddenly one day I changed the security on the wireless so I had to reconnect the printer, and after it was reconnected none of the computers could find it, even those with the Canon software installed.

Comment: Have you installed the printer driver on the computers in question? Note that you will also need the wireless printer port installed if it is to work. When viewing the driver properties, you should be able to find the Canon wireless port among LPT1, COM1, USB, etc.

Comment: is used to just appear in the Network windows where all the network devices are displayed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Network devices getting an IP address in the 169.254.x.x range?](https://superuser.com/questions/1106931/network-devices-getting-an-ip-address-in-the-169-254-x-x-range)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is had "stopped working" was because I had turned off WSD thinking it was to do with security and so it didn't show up in network.

Answer (score 3):

IPs in the 169.254.x.x subnet are automatically assigned using automatic private IP addressing when no DHCP server can be reached (and therefore no proper IP has been assigned). Typically, this can happen if you accidentally connect a printer (or other device) to a network where no DHCP server is present (or for example if you plug the printer directly into your computer via Ethernet).

If possible, try hard-coding the printer's IP address to a valid address in the 192.168.2.x subnet.

Otherwise, double-check all the cabling to ensure that you're really connected to the network properly.

You  may also try resetting both the router and the printer to see if perhaps either the DHCP server on the router or the DHCP client on the printer malfunctioned in some way.

Some info on Wikipedia is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#Address_autoconfiguration).

Comment: Well I tried it wireless and it still will not be found by any of the computers on my network, although it says the IP address is 192.168.2.6 and I can access the printers page by going to the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

> Well I tried it wireless and it still will not be found by any of the computers on my network, although it says the IP address is 192.168.2.6 and I can access the printers page by going to the IP address.
>
> But because the printer has a USB slot for Flash drives it shows up in network as a computer (so you can acccess the USB drive over the network), an normally both the computer and printer show up in Network Devices but now only the computer is.
>
> So it is aware the printer as a device is there, but it doesn't recognize the printer side of things

Only if the printer implements printing support through SMB. You may need to install the printer as a local printer using a TCP/IP port.

Note that you will want to give the printer a static DHCP lease from your router for this, if the printer doesn't have a hostname.

Comment: The printer has worked fine before without any additional changes, just copying the wireless settings on to a pendirve and then plugging the pendrive into the printer.